# How to select record with highest date found in two datetime columns?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return the record of in table that has the highest date in two separate DATETIME columns.

For example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| ID |       DATE1       |       DATE2          |  OTHERDATA |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |2016-02-16 17:14:10| NULL                 |     3      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |2016-02-29 10:14:51| 2016-03-03 12:43:39  |     3      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  3 |2016-03-03 12:43:39| 2016-03-10 01:00:00  |     3      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

MYSQL query I have to far:

```
SELECT *, GREATEST(COALESCE(DATE1,0), 
     COALESCE(DATE2,0)) 
FROM Table 
WHERE OTHERDATA = 3
GROUP BY OTHERDATA;
```

I am expecting this query to **return ID 3** but instead it **returns ID 1**. I am assuming it has something to do with the NULL but I thought COALESCE would handle that? Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the GROUP BY clause. There are no aggregate functions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
   FROM table
 WHERE otherdata = 3
 ORDER
    BY GREATEST(COALESCE(DATE1,0), 
 COALESCE(DATE2,0)) DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: While it may seem obvious, some brief hint as to why this way might make this a better answer

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!